# how can I append a new field to Symfony form?

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, input

I am trying to append a new input field to my symfony form using javascript,
I want to pass some data with the form submission.

This what I tried to do :

```
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
      var hiddenInput = document.createElement('newInput');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'newInputName');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', "newInputValue");
      form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
      form.submit();
});
```

But I am stuck on how to get the new submitted input.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I assume that if you add an identifier to the new element, you will be able to access the element. I really don't understand your problem. Could you give us some more information?

Comment: This is the `hidden` field, why don't you include it by default in your Symfony `Form` instance and just set the value on submit?

Comment: @PabloM. I have a form with only "name" and "email", after clicking submit I want to create this new element and send it to the controller with the form.
I have to do it without adding this new field to the Form instance

Comment: @JovanPerovic I have to do it without adding this new field to the Form instance

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. The Form will scream at you about getting an unexpected field...

Comment: You can set the [`allow_extra_fields`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#allow-extra-fields) option to avoid the form refusing to pass validation. But, _why_ do you want to do so? Have you looked into [dynamic forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)? _Why_ can't you have them in the form or add them after the fact? Is this some kind of imposed requirement?

Comment: @4212 Please describe precisely what you're trying to achieve.  As already mentioned by Jovan Perovic, by default, forms *do not let you do this*. It has security reasons! 
If you're trying "to mark" the form this way - it's not the right way :) To tell you what would be better - we need more context.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the Symfony form instead? It's going to be easier to use.
You can call an Ajax request to the controller, create a form using the Symfony's Form System and make the request to return a template with the fields. I enclose you an easy example:

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/myAjaxRequest", name="your_route_name", options={"expose"=true}, methods={"POST"})
 * @return Response
 */
public function myAjaxAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(YourFormType::class, $yourObject, []);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //Whatever you want if you submit the form 
            return new Response('1');
        }
    }

    return $this->render('mytemplate.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

The Form:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Form;
    
    use...

    class MyFormType extends AbstractType
    {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('your_field', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'This is my field!'
            ])
        ]);
    }
    }
```

The template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.your_field) }}
//If you want to add your custom field via HTML, this will be submitted
<input type="checkbox" id="add_your_field"/>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Hope this helps